# Replicating BigQuery UDFs

Tags: python, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to replicate the UDF from one dataset to another. However, copying the dataset ignores anything that is not a table (including UDFs and views).

I tried [retrieving the UDF from the table object](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table) but there is no such property. It appears there is a [UDF property attached to a query](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.query.UDFResource.html?highlight=udf#google.cloud.bigquery.query.UDFResource), however, that does not provide the inline code.

Is there a way to obtain the UDF from one dataset and copy to another? It doesn't seem possible on the surface, but I could be missing something.

Comment: How are you trying to replicate the UDF? Could you provide more details? and the errors you are getting?

Comment: We are currently copying and pasting through the UI. We're not seeing anything related to UDFs in the Google Client Libraries so there wouldn't be code to show and no errors to report. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that currently is not possible to copy UDF from Dataset A to Dataset B using the API because it is limited to tables and views.

However, there is an Issue Tracker report requesting this kind of features.

http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150780188